# Select specific (grand) parent

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have following

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>
          </f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
  <m>
  </m>
</a>
```

Whenever `f` is clicked I want to hide `m`. I can do this

```
$('f').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().hide();
});
```

But it is not hard and fast rule that after 4 parents, `b` would be found. But `m` is always next to the `b`.

Note: I also donot want to run a `for` loop to check `if` element is `b` or not. I want pure Jquery solution.

Comment: `$(this).closest('b').next().hide(); or $(this).closest('b').siblings('m').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest().siblings()` or `.closest().next()` would be your helpers in jQuery:

```
$('f').click(function() {
  // $(this).closest('b').next().hide();
  $(this).closest('b').siblings('m').hide();
});
```

as i guess `.closest().siblings()` would be better one because if you append any other memeber in your markup before `m` it would work as intended.

#### From the docs:

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest):  For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings): Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

---

*I also donot want to run a for loop to check if element is b or not.*

I want to mention that `.closest()` method internally uses `for()` loop to get to the matched parent. here is the source of `closest`:

```
closest: function( selectors, context ) {
        var cur,
            i = 0,
            l = this.length,
            matched = [],
            pos = rneedsContext.test( selectors ) || typeof selectors !== "string" ?
                jQuery( selectors, context || this.context ) :
                0;

        for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
            for ( cur = this[i]; cur && cur !== context; cur = cur.parentNode ) {
                // Always skip document fragments
                if ( cur.nodeType < 11 && (pos ?
                    pos.index(cur) > -1 :

                    // Don't pass non-elements to Sizzle
                    cur.nodeType === 1 &&
                        jQuery.find.matchesSelector(cur, selectors)) ) {

                    matched.push( cur );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return this.pushStack( matched.length > 1 ? jQuery.unique( matched ) : matched );
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects the n-th(in this case 4th) parent of the clicked element, change the input of eq to

> 0

for the first parent and to

> 99

for the 100th parent, the size of the line will stay the same

```
$('f').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(3).next().hide();  // "Great-Great-grandfather".
})
```